# Typescript Check if "any n consecutive elements are same" in M size array

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq, typescript, linq.js

I've an array of strings or numbers of size M(M>n). I want to check if any n consecutive elements are same where n can vary between 1-M.

For instance, let assume I've below array, and I want to check there are four consecutive '5's or two consecutive '3's are present or not:

{1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,2,6,3,3,1}

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I'm also using Linq.JS to perform linq functions on array.

Comment: This is a typical reduce job.

Comment: @Redu.. **reduce** with the external counter?

Comment: No external counters... I'll try t post an answer once i have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do as follows

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,2,6,3,3,1],
 result = arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c !== a[i+1] ? (p[p.length-1][0] = c, p.concat([[0,1]]))
                                               : (p[p.length-1][0] = c, p[p.length-1][1]++, p),[[true,1]])
             .slice(0,-1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's giving me the something else altogether.

Comment: @Pratik Gaikwad it gives you an array with each item's consecutive repeat count. Map it as you like.

Comment: Might want to cache previous value, the `p[p.length-1][0]` operation can become time consuming if the array was many thousands in size.  Points for brevity.